# Adding BlazorWasm to existing ASP.NET Core application

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly

I am trying to add BlazorWasm to my existing ASP.NET Core application, and I couldn't get it to work so far. It is worth noting that my existing app is using net6.0 and so is my BlazorWasm application. The steps I took to do so, are:

1. Add a new BlazorWasm project to my solution (with ASP.NET Core Hosted unchecked)
   2.Comment out this line of Program.cs file in BlazorWasm project: `builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");`
2. Add a reference of BlazorWasm project to the existing ASP.NET Core application
3. Install the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server package on the existing ASP.NET Core application
4. Add these (bold) lines to Program.cs file in ASP.NET Core project:

```
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
}
**else
{
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}**

**app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
app.MapFallbackToFile("/wwwroot/index.html");**
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

6. Add `<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>` to the head tag of `_Layout` file in ASP.NET Core application.
7. Add a blazor component to one of the views, using a reference to the BlazorWasm and this line:

```
<component type="typeof(Counter)" render-mode="WebAssemblyPrerendered" />
```

But when I run the app, although the Counter component is shown on the view, the `Click Me` button does not work and when I check the Console, there's a request to download `blazor.webassembly.js` with a 404 response.

I tried several things, including manually copying the `_framework` folder into the wwwroot directory, but no luck so far.

**** UPDATE ****

I was able to solve the problem. The main problem was that my IIS Express was not Environment variables was not set to `Development`, so the `app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();` would not be executed at runtime. After setting it to Development, the `blazor.webassembly.js` file was served in the browser, but then another problem aroused. The `blazor.boot.json` could not be found. I noticed that when requesting the file, the url was something like this: `http://localhost/Landing/blazor.boot.json`. Because in my application, base url after authentication is /Landing! So by changing the script address in `index.html` to `<script src="/Landing/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>`, now my Blazor component is working!